# Rendering 3D in Processing

Tags: processing

Has anybody experienced a problem rendering 3D images in Processing where smaller size canvases (E.g. 2000x2000) render fine, but larger canvases (4000x4000) don't render at all?

Comment: It's possible it's a limit of your GPU. What does it say your max texture size is here? http://webglreport.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help @gman! Here's the texture size report: 

Textures  
Max Texture Size: 16384  
Max Cube Map Texture Size: 16384  
Max Combined Texture Image Units: 32  
Max Anisotropy: 16